# Shows the number of children per family for 50 families in a housing estate

Tags: statistics

Shows the number of children per family for 50 families in a housing estate

$$\begin{array}{cc}
\textrm{No. of Children} &\textrm{No. Of Families} \\
          0&                    4\\
          1&                    m\\
          2&                    n\\
          3&                    8\\
          4&                    4\\
          5&                    2\\
\end{array}
$$
If MIN is 2, find m and n.

Comment: please, add homework to your homework questions, and use LaTeX to add style

Answer (score 2):

Here is a wild guess about the information we are given. I will assume that when you write that MIN is $2$, you mean that the **mean** number of children per family is $2$.

There are $50$ families. But we can see by adding up the entries in the column on the right that there are $18+m+n$ families. So $50=18+m+n$, and therefore $m+n=32$.

The mean number of children per family is $2$. The mean is the total number of children divided by the number of families. So if $T$ is the total number of children, then $\frac{T}{50}=2$, meaning that $T=100$.

But from the table,
$$T=(0)(4)+(1)(m)+(2)(n)+(3)(8)+(4)(4)+(5)(2).$$
Simplify. We find that $T=50+m+2n$. But $T=100$, so $50+m+2n=100$ and therefore $m+2n=50$.

We now have the two linear equations $m+n=32$ and $m+2n=50$.  By subtraction, we find that $n=(m+2n)-(m+n)=50-32=18$.

But then since $m+n=32$, we have $m=14$.